# How do I change the Image of only 1 button in Collection View and make all other button Images different in Swift

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, uibutton, uiimage

In my collection view I have songs with play buttons. I want to change the image of my button upon selection and want to make the previous selected button image to revert to default image. The buttons are in an unknown amount could be anywhere between 1 to 20. Any Help would be appreciated.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    
    if collectionView == self.albumCollection {
    let cellA = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "album", for: indexPath) as! AlbumsCollectionViewCell
        
        cellA.albumImg.image = UIImage(named: albums[indexPath.row])
        cellA.albumLbl.text = albumLbl[indexPath.row]
        
        
    return cellA
    }
    else {
        let cellB = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "songs", for: indexPath) as! ForYouCollectionViewCell
        
        cellB.forImg.image = UIImage(named: songs[indexPath.row])

        cellB.forButton.tag = indexPath.row
        cellB.delegate = self
               return cellB
    }
    
}
```

and here is code for my collection view cell

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation


protocol SongDelegate: AnyObject {
func songBtnTapped(sender: UIButton!)
}

class ForYouCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {

@IBOutlet weak var forImg: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var forButton: UIButton!
weak var delegate: SongDelegate?

var isTapped = false
var player: AVPlayer?
var counts: Int = 0
//test

override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self,selector: #selector(songBtn(_:)),name: Notification.Name("playSong"),object: nil)

}



func conditions() {
    
    
    if isTapped == false {
        forButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "wPlay"), for: .normal)
        isTapped = true


    } else {
        forButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "wPause"), for: .normal)
        isTapped = false
    }
    

    
}

@IBAction func songBtn(_ sender: UIButton) {
    delegate?.songBtnTapped(sender: sender)
    forButton.setImage(UIImage(named: ("wPause")), for: .normal)

    print(sender.tag)
    counts = sender.tag
    if counts == sender.tag {
        print(counts)
        forButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "wPlay"), for: .normal)
    } else if counts != sender.tag {
        
        forButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "wPause"), for: .normal)
    }

   
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

have a variable on your collectionView ViewController that has the songPlaying: Int? and then in your cellForItemAt function you can check if indexPath.row == songPlaying show play else show pause. Have clicking on the button change the songPlaying to that tag and reload your collectionView. I am not sure where your conditions func is being used, but that seems unnecessary you should just have a buttonImage variable on the cell and set it in the cellForItemAt.

Comment: Thanks a lot, can you tell me one more thing, i want to make the play button back to pause when i click the same button 2 times. Can you please help me with that

Comment: When setting the songPlaying you can check if current song playing equals new one and if so set songPlaying to nil or -1